# How can i use my iPhone to scan a barcode and send it to my EV3 brick?

Tags: ev3, ios

I'm trying to build a sorter that scans the barcode on the brick using an iPhone and sorts it accordingly to the barcode. I cannot use colours due to amount of things to sort.

Comment: There are many Apps available on the App store that can scan barcodes and export the data via e-mail/dropbox etc. However your main problem will be latency. Unless you're prepared to program your own app ([as David suggests](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4401/132)) it may be worth considering other options.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write an application for your phone that can scan the codes and then send the information to the EV3 via bluetooth or wifi.

If you don't know how to write iOS apps, start [here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios).

For scanning bar codes there seems to be good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios). It appears that bar code scanning is built into iOS 7. If you have an older version, the the zxing library sounds like a good choice.

For communicating to the EV3 over bluetooth, this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677386/bluetooth-connection-to-lego-mindstorms-ev3-brick-from-ios-app). However, I have yet to come across a good example.

You should be able to figure out the communication protocol for communicating with the EV3 from the LEGO firmware [documentation](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/index.html), [VM documentation](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen-all/index.html) and [source code](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources).